# Odoo show taxes in general ledger report

Tags: odoo, accounting

How can I show the taxes in the General Ledger Report in Odoo.

[image]

I tried adding the field in the column section but it seems to not be working the values in taxes column for all entries are blank.

I'm not sure how to approach this, maybe I need to override a method or I'm maybe adding the wrong field.

Comment: Could you provide more details please ?